# XSS attack in client's IP address

Tags: php, security, ip, xss, htmlspecialchars

I want to count unique visitors on my webpage. I get client's IP using following function:

```
$ipaddress = '';
    if ($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    else if($_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['HTTP_FORWARDED'];
    else if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        $ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    else
        $ipaddress = 'UNKNOWN';
    return $ipaddress;
```

Should I call the `htmlspecialchars()` function on it, before inserting it into database? I have heard it is possible to manipulate headers and change IP address to add to it XSS or SQL Injection (I already call `real_escape_string()` function) attack.

Comment: You should **never** HTML-escape a value that you store in a database column.  You should only escape text when you concatenate it into that format.  You need to understand what escaping means.

Comment: @SLaks I want to display it (this IP) in administrator view. So it possibliy could be the vector of attack

Comment: Concatenating it into HTML is an issue.  Storing it in a database isn't.  (although you need to use parameters)

Comment: @SLaks So should I run only `real_escape_string()` on this IP?

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32299/is-server-a-safe-source-of-data-in-php has information on which ones you can safely use and which ones the user can manipulate.

Comment: Because possibliy somebody can make his IP to e.g. `10.0.0.1<script>//...</script>`. And then, when it gonna by displayed, I will contain bad code

Comment: No; you should use parameters for SQL queries, and HTML-escape when creating HTML.

Comment: OK, but why that gonna by mistake to use `htmlspecialchars` before I insert data to DB?

Comment: @Ty221 "Because possibliy somebody can make his IP to e.g. 10.0.0.1<script>//...</script>." First, that'd be fairly difficult. Any popular webserver will ignore it, too.

Comment: @Ty221 "OK, but why that gonna by mistake to use htmlspecialchars before I insert data to DB?" It should be done on the display end, not the database end. Changing the data the user submits can have unintended consequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the data type you're expecting is an IP, you should simply validate for that specific data type
Add the following to your code

```
if(filter_var($ipaddress, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) return $ipaddress;
else return "Unknown";
```

This basically validates that it's an actual IP so that no SQL Injection attack vectors or even XSS could pass through it.